# Drag and Drop using swift 4 on mac OS

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard, swift4

I'm using swift 4 and Xcode 9 and I have a problem with implementation of drag and drop. I have a custom 'destination' view for drops and in swift 3 i call

```
register(forDraggedTypes: Array(NSURLPboardType))
```

to accept drags that contain those types.
How can I do somethings like this in swift 4? 
Now I have this code

```
registerForDraggedTypes([.pdf])
```

And no one NSDraggingDestination method calls when I drop a pdf in my view. 
(my custom view sits on top)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So my colleague found solution of this problem, in swift 4 you have to use kUTTypes casted as String for drag and drop, like this:

```
registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: kUTTypeFileURL as String), NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: kUTTypeItem as String)])
```

With this code all NSDraggingDestination methods works fine, you can drop any file from finder in your view.

Comment: You can just use `"public.file-url"` instead of `kUTTypeFileURL as String`.

Comment: `"public.item"` instead `kUTTypeItem as String`

Comment: On newer mac versions you can do it like `registerForDraggedTypes([.fileURL])`